# How to change ViewController to avoid memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm making game app that you can play 1~30 stages. When you proceed to next stage, I use this code

```
        var stageViewController: StageBaseViewController?

        switch stageNumber {
        case 1:
            stageViewController = Stage02Controller()
        case 2:
            stageViewController = Stage03Controller()
        case 3:
            stageViewController = Stage04Controller()  
        ...          
        case 29:
            stageViewController = Stage30Controller()
        default:
            print("error: unknown stage number.")
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(stageViewController!, animated: true)
```

But if you play some stages in a row, memory leak is caused. 
How can I avoid this problem?

*UPDATE

The ViewController transition of this app is

```
A < B < C(gamestage)
```

And I tried to set ViewControllers like this

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([aVC, bVC, cVC], animated: true)
```

But then old cVC's deinit didn't work. So I tried to remove old VC by this code

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeLast()
```

But self.navigationController?.viewControllers was nil.

When I set 3 VCs deinit wasn't called so memory was increased.
But set only 1 VC (cVC), deinit was called.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bao, If you need you player to have ability to go previous stages - the correct approach in this situation - save passed levels data instead of saving every UIViewController.

Then you can allocate UIViewControllers as they need, e.g.:

```
Stage04Controller(data: SomePlayerData)
```

Where SomePlayerData can contain player position on stage, defeated monsters or treasures positions and so on.

When you do - you shouldn't push new view controllers to navigation stack every time user changes stage. Instead you just replace them, so in one moment of game - only one instance of view controller will exist.

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([stageViewController], animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code worked well, and memory didn't increase. But new trouble did appear. I updated my code so please check it up.

Comment: @bao, keep in memory only last stage view controller. When Your player on the 3rd stage and presses back button - perform `self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([Stage02Controller()], animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

When you push new view controller, old view controller isn't removed from navigation controller and isn't deallocated.

You need to replace old view controller with new view controller:

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([stageViewController!], animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I updated my code and new problem, so please check it.